# MySQL left join, less results

Tags: mysql, join

I've got a little problem, I'm stuck with. I got two tables. The first one holds all id's, the second one some, but not all from tableA, a value and a corresponding identifier. As I thought I had it understood, a left join on the id's should give me all id's in the first table and null for the second, if the id doesn't exist in tableB. But I keep getting the number of id's that exist in both tables. Did I get the concept wrong?

My statement so far is:

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.desiredValue
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id=tableB.item_id
WHERE tableB.element_id = 'something'
OR tableB.element_id IS NULL;
```

Any pointers?

Thanx, best regards,
Marcus

Comment: Try it without the `WHERE` clause. You don't use `element_id` anywhere else in the query - perhaps `element_id` is never NULL?  You do have the concept correct, and if you start by eliminating the WHERE, you'll probably see something closer to what you expect.

Comment: Failing that, show us a handful of rows as sample data

Comment: So you want to show all items from tableA, and if there are corresponding items in tableB, also show those from tableB?

Comment: Yes. In tableA, I have say 1000 id's. In tableB, which is a cross-reference-table (or whatever that's called), most id's appear several times, being a unique key together with a second field, that identifies say the name or the street. The join now always returns the number of rows that equal all id's where the desired value exists. e.g. tableA: id=5, tableB: row1: item_id=5, type=1, value=bla row2: item_id=5, type=2, value=blubb. item_id=7, type=1, value=ping. On this table, if I query for type=1, I get 2 results, even having 3 rows?!

Comment: @MarcusToepper If you query for `type=1`, you will only get back the rows that match.  In your query above you use `OR element_id IS NULL`, which would return nulls for `element_id`.  Please edit your question above with actual rows from your database and what you expect your output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition that involves `tableB` column from `WHERE` to `ON`:

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.desiredValue
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON  tableA.id=tableB.item_id
                 AND tableB.element_id = 'something'

--- WHERE tableB.element_id IS NULL        --- this is probably not appropriate
;
```

Comment: Nice! I had the tableA.id=tableB.item_id-bit in a WHERE-clause. Moving that the way described above, it does it's job. Very nice, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.desiredValue
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id=tableB.item_id
AND (tableB.element_id = 'something'
OR tableB.element_id IS NULL);
```

Comment: Making the `WHERE` part of the `ON` is a bit odd a way of doing things... Add to this the lack of any explanation about why this is better than the code in the OP, and you get a `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this seems like it should work. I'd be more specific in the where clause, however:

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.desiredValue
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.item_id
WHERE tableB.element_id = 'something' OR tableB.item_id IS NULL;
```

I've substituted `item_id` as the row I'm checking for `NULL` in -- though it should make a difference unless `element_id` can be `NULL` in rows where the join works.

Can you expand on why you want the other portion of the where clause -- `tableB.element_id = 'something'` ? My general recommendation if you just want all rows returned would be to eliminate the WHERE clause entirely.

Can you explain a bit more what the criteria are for the rows you want returned in general?